# C++ Detour on winsock recv hooking - custom packet

Tags: c++, recv, detours

I'm trying to add additional packet in `MyRecv` function, but  I don't know why it doesn't working. I tried to parse incoming packets and function works fine.
So probably my way to sending custom packet to application isn't properly.

In general assumption I just want send prepared packet to application.
This packet i took from WPE PRO.

Code with MyRecv function:

```
INT WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET sock, CHAR* buf, INT len, INT flags) {
  CHAR buffer[256];

  char msg2[] = { 0x1B, 0, 0x04, 0x06, 0, 0x5A, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x61,
                  0x78, 0x06, 0, 0x5A, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x61, 0x78, 0x05, 0x07, 0,
                  0x66, 0x61, 0x6A, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x65, 0x65 };

  int ret = precv(sock, buf, len, flags);
  if (ret <= 0) {
    return ret;
  }

  if (fake_recv) {
    char tmp[256];
    fake_recv = false;
    printf("Fake1-> Lenght:%d Size:%d", len, strlen(buf));
    strcat(buf, msg2);
    printf("Fake2-> Lenght:%d Size:%d", len, strlen(buf));
    return ret;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg2` isn't a null-terminated string. In fact it has an interior null. So using `strlen()` and `strcat()` with it is never going to work.

Similarly you neither know nor care what's already in `buf,` so calling `strcat()` and `strlen()` on that is both pointless and dangerous: if it contains no nulls at all you will over-run it, and at best over-report the length, and at worst crash.

And you're not adjusting `ret` for the extra data added into the buffer.

And no useful purpose is accomplished by declaring the unused `tmp[]` variable.

Try this:

```
if (fake_recv) {                                        
    fake_recv = false;
    printf("Fake1-> Length:%d Received:%d", len, ret);
    int len2 = min(len-ret, sizeof msg2);
    memcpy(&buf[ret], msg2, len2);
    ret += len2;
    printf("Fake2-> Length:%d Received:%d", len, ret);
    return ret;         
}
```